# form and input fields not functioning correctly using .append()

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to append a form to the body of my document within my .js file. I press a button 'Proceed' and the form appears. The form is displaying correctly on screen, however the input field is not allowing for text input.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<div id="checkout"><button id="checkout2">Proceed </button></div>');
    $('#checkout').one('click', function(e) {

        $('body').html(
            '<div id="payarea"><h1 size="50"><u>Checkout</u> </h1></ br>' +

            '<form method="post" action="nav.html" >' +
            '<table width=518 border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >' +
              '<tr> ' +
                '<td height="22" colspan="3" align="center" ><strong>Billing Information </strong></td>' +
              '</tr>'+
              '<tr> '+
                '<td height="22" width="180" align="right" >Full name:</td>'+
                '<td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="text"  size="50"></td>'+
              '</tr>'+

            '</table>'+
            '<input id="payment1" type="submit" value="Send name">'+
            '</form>'+
            ' </div>');

    });
});
```

The css.

```
input:not([type]) {
    padding: 1px 0px;
}
user agent stylesheetinput {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px inset;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    cursor: auto;
}
user agent stylesheetinput {
    margin: 0em;
    font: normal normal normal normal 13.3333330154419px/normal Arial;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
}
user agent stylesheetinput {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
```

Comment: `</ br>` should be `<br />` and an input field without a name isn't submitted to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implement your code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6re63nn9/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="checkout"><button id="checkout2">Proceed </button></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkout').one('click', function(e) {

        $('body').html(
            '<div id="payarea"><h1 size="50"><u>Checkout</u> </h1></ br>' +

            '<form method="post" action="nav.html" >' +
            '<table width=518 border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >' +
              '<tr> ' +
                '<td height="22" colspan="3" align="center" ><strong>Billing Information </strong></td>' +
              '</tr>'+
              '<tr> '+
                '<td height="22" width="180" align="right" >Full name:</td>'+
                '<td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="text"  size="50"></td>'+
              '</tr>'+

            '</table>'+
            '<input id="payment1" type="submit" value="Send name">'+
            '</form>'+
            ' </div>');

    });
});
```

The input field is allowing to text input, so there's no problem, unless there was other code to make the input field read-only or disabled. Right-click on your element and use **Inspect Element** to see field properties.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at the css properties on the page, and I can't seem to find anything to suggest the fields are disabled. I'll paste the css properties above.

Comment: Whats your browser? Do you have an online version to check it out? I applied your CSS but still it is working.

Comment: It seems you left this question. Please don't forget to mark as accepted answer, if your problem solved!!!